# java Graphics window only updates when resized

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;



//import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

class Rectangle extends JPanel {
   private static int rect_x = 40;
   private static int rect_y = 40;
   private static final int rect_width = 100;
   private static final int rect_height = rect_width;




    KeyListener listener;

    public Rectangle() {

            this.listener = new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                //System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());

                // w
                if(e.getKeyCode() == 87)
                {
                    rect_y -= 10;
                    //revalidate();
                    repaint();

                }
                // s
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == 83)
                {
                    rect_y += 10;
                    repaint();

                }
                // a
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == 65)
                {
                    rect_x -= 10;
                    repaint();

                }
                // d
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == 68)
                {
                    rect_x += 10;
                    repaint();


                }
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }
        };  }





   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height);
    g.fillRect(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      // so that our GUI is big enough
      return new Dimension(rect_width + 2 * rect_x, rect_height + 2 * rect_y);   
   }

   // create the GUI explicitly on the Swing event thread
   private void createAndShowGui() {
      Rectangle mainPanel = new Rectangle();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawRect");

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.addKeyListener(listener);
   }




   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rectangle Rct = new Rectangle();
            Rct.createAndShowGui();


        }

      });



   }
}
```

this code is meant to move a rectangle across the screen. 
For some reason it does not update unless the window is minimised or resized.

I realise this has been asked many times before, but the answers I have found were very case specific or above my understanding. 
I am new to java so sorry if I seem like a blockhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating an Extra Rectangle object, and calling repaint() on it, and this is not the displayed object, and so your listener does not repaint the displayed JPanel. Don't do this. Only create *one* Rectangle object, so your repaints go to the correct reference.

e.g., change this:

```
  Rectangle mainPanel = new Rectangle();  // ***** no!!! ****

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawRect");

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);  // **** no ****
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.addKeyListener(listener);
```

to this:

```
  // Rectangle mainPanel = new Rectangle();

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawRect");

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(this);  // ****** note change
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.addKeyListener(listener);
```

Other side issues:

- Prefer Key Bindings to a KeyListener
- Avoid magic numbers such as your key code numbers, which make debugging difficult. Instead use the `KeyEvent.VK_?` constants.
- Follow Java naming conventions: constants should be all upper-case.
- Your rect_x and y fields should not be static.

Comment: ok thanks that works now, and also thanks for explaining why it was not working :)

Comment: the variables were recently changed, thanks for pointing that out. what do you mean by magic numbers?

Comment: I still want to use a non static thing, how do I call that now?

Comment: just started another program and this is still useful!